# Android FusedLocationProviderApi: Incoming intent has no LocationResult or LocationAvailability

Tags: android, location

I am trying to subscribe to location updates via Google's FusedLocationProviderApi. I want to receive updates in the background, so that I will receive updates even if the app is killed. Following the online documentation as best as I can, I've written the following code. Note: this is being done in an intent service, not on the UI thread, which is why I'm using blocking connect/result methods.

```java
private void startLocationServices(String deviceId, int pollingInterval) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting location services with interval: " + pollingInterval + "ms");
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    final PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    wakeLock.acquire();

    final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient =
            new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

    ConnectionResult result = googleApiClient.blockingConnect();

    if (!result.isSuccess() || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect to Google Api");
        wakeLock.release();
        return;
    }

    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(pollingInterval);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    Intent locationIntent = new Intent(this, GeoBroadcastReceiver.class);
    locationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_UPDATE_DEVICE_ID, deviceId);
    locationIntent.setAction(GeoBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_LOCATION_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent locationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, 0, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PendingResult pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, locationPendingIntent);

    Result requestResult = pendingResult.await();
    Status requestStatus = requestResult.getStatus();

    if (requestStatus.isSuccess()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed to location updates.");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format(
                        "Failed subscribe to location updates. Error code: %d, Message: %s.",
                        requestStatus.getStatusCode(),
                        requestStatus.getStatusMessage()));
    }

    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    wakeLock.release();
}
```

When I run this, I see that `requestStatus.isSuccess()` returns true, indicating that I've successfully subscribed to the location updates. Additionally, The `GeoBroadcastReciever`, which extends `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, receives an intent at the correct polling interval, with the correct action. Good so far, it would seem. Here is what I'm doing in the `onReceive` method for the `GeoBroadcastReceiver`:

```java
    if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        if (location != null) {
            GeoMonitoringService.wakefulLocationUpdate(context, location);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationResult does not contain a LastLocation.");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Intent does not contain a LocationResult.");
    }
```

The problem is, whenever the intent comes in, it does not contain the `LocationResult`, nor does it contain the `LocationAvailabilityResult`. I inspected the incoming intent in the debugger, and the only item in the intent's extras is the extra I added when setting up the intent (the device id). As such, `LocationResult.hasResult()` returns false. Every single time.

I've tried this on a Galaxy Note 4 running 4.0.1, and a Nexus 4 running 5.1.1, with the same result.

If I disable location on the phone, I stop receiving intents altogether, as expected.

Comment: Ok, I have more data on this. When I comment out the line that adds the String Extra to the intent before passing it to `getBroadcast()`, the problem is _mostly_ cleared up. In that case, the problem only occurs with about 1 in 20 location updates. With the Extra present, the problem happens every time. I know this seems a little tenuous, but the pattern is very repeatable on both of my phones. Something about adding that extra seems to mess things up (although in the case of ActivityRecognition, where I'm using the exact same pattern, the presence of the Extra does not seem to matter at all).

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems the same reported one year ago here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81812. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet found a solution to this.

Comment: OK. a workaround (Christophe Beyls suggested that only Intent Data should be used)
so, since I only need to send a few parameters, so I do something like this:
while building the Intent before the requestLocationUpdates:
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://a.com/a?"+ Param1+ "?" + Param2+ "?" + Param3);
and in the BroadcastReceiver:
String[] parameters = intent.getDataString().split("[?]");
This works fine, and intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED)
does return the location.

Comment: Did you find the solutuion

Answer (score 14):

Remove the extras from the pending intent, otherwise the location result is not delivered. I can't find where in the documentation this is explained but I found out after lot of trial and error.

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119995978) for this.

Comment: I hope they look at your bug report soon. It feels gross to pass a parameter in the data URI.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround (Christophe Beyls suggested that only Intent Data should be used)
So, since I only need to send a few parameters, so I do something like this:
while building the Intent before the requestLocationUpdates:
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://a.com/a?"+ Param1+ "?" + Param2+ "?" + Param3);
and in the BroadcastReceiver:
String[] parameters = intent.getDataString().split("[?]");
This works fine, and intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED)
does return the location.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
int id = 7;
String name = "myName";
uriBuilder.scheme("http")
            .authority("workaround.com")
            .appendPath("extra")
            .appendQueryParameter("id", String.valueOf(id))
            .appendQueryParameter("name", name);
intent.setData(uriBuilder.build());
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        int id = Integer.valueOf(uri.getQueryParameter("id"));
        String name = uri.getQueryParameter("name");
        ....
    }
}
```